# Is there a name for a control which allows a user to add/remove table rows?

Tags: controls, terminology

I am building a control which is a table containing other controls (text boxes and dropdown lists) where the user can add/remove rows to the table. I am unsure of what to name this control and am wondering if there is a standrad name for such a thing. Here is an (un-stylized) example:

---

[image: Example]

---

The columns in the control can very, but every row will always have the same controls for each instance of this control. In the example shown, the control is for choosing data sources and giving the sources labels. In every instance of this control, each row will have a "remove" button, and the user will be able to add new rows.

Right now my code calls this an `AddRemoveTableControl`, which is horrid. What is the proper name for such a control?

Comment: We call it an inline editor since you're adding/editing things all inline. We use this terminology when relating to any sort of control that lets you add/remove/edit multiple items at a time.

Comment: Sorry, is this in regards to the name of the control presented in the UI or just the name of the control within the code?

Comment: This is the name of the control *in the code* @TomR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a "RowCollection" control?

This is an array of rows

- we can force an additional row to the end, initialized to defaults
- we can remove a row based on positional notation
- So the underlying mechanic is an array of one or more columns
- each record in the array is one row, consisting of one or more columns

So it's technically a rowcollection

Comment: I love this! It fits my need very well.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel and Google Docs call this **"Insert/Delete Row."**

So, you might call it insertRow and deleteRow.

Comment: This is a single control, so should I call it an `InsertDeleteRowControl`?

Comment: No, this is two controls that appear together on one panel.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a customization dialogue (you can call it Customize). MS Outlook has a window called Field Chooser, which seems to me like a good name.